# Magento cache is turned off but still caching files

Tags: php, magento

I am running magento 1.5.1 and when turning off caching for debugging, files are still being cached.

Can anyone advise on how to fully disable the caching mechanism in magento?

Comment: i have this problem in 1.6 i tried setting cache directory to 444 but it breaks the system.

Answer (score 1):

delete everything under var/cache/ to fully flush your file based cache. If your site is using APC, EACCELERATOR, MEMCACHED or other cache engines you might need to clear or disable those as well

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what I am doing.  I disable caching in the admin area then manually delete every file under var/cache.  After the deletion is finished i refresh that directory and it has already started caching again.  No apc or memecache

Comment: Does not help. Still cached.